# Crosswalks (aka Matrix) for InfoSec Compliance Standards

Tags: pci-dss, compliance, hipaa, iso27000

Looking to find a reference that maps the various control standards (i.e. HIPAA, PCI-DSS, GLBA, ISO) to each other.

I envision the answer being a spreadsheet that outlines the controls for one standard (say ISO-27002) as row items and the other standards (PCI, HIPAA, GLBA) as columns with the relevant control number:

```
ISO | Desc                  | PCI | HIPAA | GLBA
-------------------------------------------------
A.1   Data Classification    3.2.1   I.8     2.7 
A.2   Asset Management       3.6.1   283.1   7.9
```

*etc...*

Here are a few examples of what I'm looking for, but something more comprehensive that includes all of the standards:

- http://www.qcert.org/sites/default/files/public/documents/cs-csps_mapping_nia_policy_iso_27001_pci_dss_v3.0.pdf
- https://www.informationshield.com/papers/ISO27002%20PCI-DSS%20V3%20Policy%20Map.pdf

Comment: Sounds like a fine piece of work - I look forward to seeing *your* output! ;-)

Comment: What you're looking for is often called a matrix - [here's an example](https://library.educause.edu/resources/2010/3/compliance-matrix-poster-for-it-compliance-professionals).

Comment: @gowenfawr other than being a little out of date this is exactly the type of thing (*matrix*) I'm looking for. Any idea where to get an updated version?

Answer (score -2):

Are you familiar with the UCF Common Controls Hub at https://commoncontrolshub.com/? It allows you to create an "Authority Documents List" using your example standards and download a spreadsheet that lets you compare them and identify gaps and overlaps. Very cool.

Comment: Bill is right. The folks at BluePrint systems worked with us to integrate this into their software in under 3 months. Everything you need to develop using the API is absolutely free, and you get a free research account in the Common Controls Hub as well. The developer URL is: https://developer.unifiedcompliance.com/ you can try everything online. If you have any questions, sign up in the slack channel (also no cost) and you can ask them there.